# HTML does not render JSX file if I import

Tags: reactjs, import, jsx

My HTML renders my jsx file if nothing is being imported, but when I do import for example bootstrap or react, nothing gets rendered

```
var Hello = React.createClass ({
    render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <p>Hello World!</p>
           <button>Test</button>
         </div>
         );
      }
});

React.Render(<Hello />. document.getElementId("reactdiv")
```

This on its own works perfectly fine, but if I import say import React from "react"; it doesn't render anything

Comment: You'll likely need to supply further information like how you're building the JS app etc., any build/console logging, and so on. I assume there's a reason you're using `createClass` manually.

Comment: Im calling my JSX app in my cshtml. <hi id="reactdiv"></hi>
and adding a react script and the src for my App.JSX file. And the solution is a WebApi btw, thus why I have to call my App.jsx in my html.

Comment: You'll likely need to supply further information like how you're building the JS app etc., any build/console logging, and so on.